# Hibernate strange behavior on self join

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I am seeing a strange behavior in Hibernate 4.3.5 and 4.3.11, where I have a table with a self join that also load other objects here is my class

```
@Entity(name = "site")
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site implements Serializable
{  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SiteAttribute> siteAttributes;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "site_id")
    private Integer siteID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ContainerPage> containerPages;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserTitle> userTitleList;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_site_id")
    private Site parentSite;
}
```

The table as a self join using the parent_site_id, and each site can have multiple son sites.

The code to retrieve the Site object is:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from site where site_id=:siteID");
q.setParameter("siteID", currentSiteID.intValue());
s = (Site) q.uniqueResult();
```

When I open the logs from hibernate the query executed look like this:

```
select ...
from site site0_ 
left outer join containers_pages containerp2_ on site0_.site_id=containerp2_.site_id 
left outer join containers container3_ on containerp2_.container_id=container3_.container_id 
left outer join pages page4_ on containerp2_.page_id=page4_.page_id 
left outer join widgets_containers widgetcont5_ on containerp2_.container_page_id=widgetcont5_.container_page_id 
left outer join site site6_ on site0_.parent_site_id=site6_.site_id 
left outer join site_attribute siteattrib7_ on site6_.site_id=siteattrib7_.site_id 
left outer join user_title usertitlel10_ on site6_.site_id=usertitlel10_.site_id where site0_.site_id=?
```

From the moment we have a left join with site using parent hibernate stops using my site0_.site_id and uses site6.site_id. Is this behavior correct?

Looks like it is missing information for the current object and this select will return much more results than it should.

Is something wrong with my implementation, or do I need to get the Site and do another query to retrieve the parent site?

Comment: I'd make `parentSite` lazy and use a separate query or an explicit join. Otherwise you could run into problems if the hierarchy is larger than 2 levels since you'd need to eagerly load the parent of the parent as well - with all the other eager attributes they have. All those joins might actually hurt performance since the result set might get really huge.

Comment: For the lazy I would need to have 1 session per request, but unfortunately that is not the case, we thought about changing that, but at this point the cost is to high, we will only be able to do that in a later date

Comment: I don't get why that should be related to the number of sessions (and what session are you talking about, Hibernate's Session?). AFAIK (I use Hibernate via JPA) you can issue multiple queries on the same Hibernate session so would there really be a problem?